# Class LaravelTournamentSeeder does not exist with package developpement

Tags: php, laravel, package

I have coded a package, and I have a problem with namespace I thinka

My plugin organisation is:

```
- database
-- factories
-- migrations
-- seeds
- resources
- src
-- MyServiceProvider
-- MyController
```

In composer.json, I have:

```
"autoload": {
"psr-4": {
  "Xoco70\\LaravelTournaments\\": "src"
},
"classmap": [
  "src/"
]
```

},

So basically, all database folder has no namespace.

When I want to call
`php artisan db:seed --class=LaravelTournamentSeeder`

I get:

```
[ReflectionException]                         
Class LaravelTournamentSeeder does not exist
```

But `LaravelTournamentSeeder` exists : first it exists in my plugin, then, it exists in my laravel installation, because I published the assets.

Any ideas???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a composer autoloading problem.

Just run command `composer dumpautoload` in your console from the project root, you should be able to run it.